# Can't get any location on Android device, while Google Maps can

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am writing an app which needs to get any fresh location. Accuracy does not metter. My app will mainly be used in buildings, so I am using Network location provider as a main location source.
I have troubles on some devices as follows:
My code can't access any location. But when I start Google Maps on the same device - it shows correct location. I switch back to my program and it does not see any location again.
My code does roughly the following:

1. Check if Network location provider is available with code below:

   locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
2. If network provider is enabled - requirest single location update:

   locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
3. Code also starts Timer for 5 seconds. If code does not get requested location update during 5 seconds, then timer is iterating throuhg all available providers trying to get last known location and pick up the best one:

   Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

The result of all these moves is that network provider is On, but code does not get any updates. Timer starts, loops through all providers and all of them does not have any last known location. getLastKnownLocation method returns null for all of them. The most strage thing is that Google Maps got correct location just a few seconds before this. I've rebooted device with no effect.
I examined best practices of getting location [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/). They seem to use the same approch as I currently do. Are there any tricks I am missing?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur in some devices the solution is try to get location from GPS if fails then get location from WIFI device

Comment: I can't use GPS as my app will  be used only inside buildings. I can't expect GPS to be available. And Google Maps can get location without GPS. GPS was actually off on this device.